# How to keep UTF-8 in batch for csv file?

Tags: powershell, csv, utf-8

Hi Stackoverflow community!

I have .csv file with some values "{Null}" and "Null". I use a batch file (.cmd) with PowerShell function to replace that values with "". 
The issue is that the output file has a different encoding (utf-16le) than the input (UTF-8). Is there a way to keep the original encoding?

```
powershell -Command "(gc myfile.csv) -replace '{NULL}', '' | Out-File myfile_replaced.csv"
```

I tried to find a solution and understood, the Notepad by default has UTF-16le encoding. Theoretically, I could change the Encoding of the Notepad++, but this is not an option, as the code should be shared with others.

And this should be implemented in Batch, otherwise I could manually Search and Replace the values.

Comment: Have you never though to look at the help for the commands you've used? When you use `Out-File`, tell it what encoding you'd, like, if using pre v6 of [tag:powershell], you can use any of the following, `ASCII`, `BigEndianUnicode`, `OEM`, `Unicode`, `UTF7`, `UTF8`, `UTF8BOM`, `UTF8NoBOM` and `UTF32`. In your case it looks like you'd use, one of the UTF8 ones, e.g `Out-File myfile_replaced.csv -Encoding UTF8`.

Comment: If the input file is UTF8 encoded (without a BOM) you need to specify the encoding also with Get-Content. [Out-File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-5.1) will inevitably include the BOM with `-Encoding UTF8` upto PSv5.1, the `-Encoding UTF8NoBOM` mentioned by @Compo is specific to PSv6+

Comment: My comment was supposed to say, 'pre v6.2', but thanks for spotting it @LotPings.

Answer (score 0):

[`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-6) supports using `-Encoding` as a parameter. This is true for various other cmdlets that write files (e.g. [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-6)) as well.

As per documentation:

> `-Encoding`
>
> Specifies the encoding for the exported CSV file. The default value is UTF8NoBOM.
>
> The acceptable values for this parameter are as follows:
>
> - ASCII: Uses the encoding for the ASCII (7-bit) character set.
> - BigEndianUnicode: Encodes in UTF-16 format using the big-endian byte order.
> - OEM: Uses the default encoding for MS-DOS and console programs.
> - Unicode: Encodes in UTF-16 format using the little-endian byte order.
> - UTF7: Encodes in UTF-7 format.
> - UTF8: Encodes in UTF-8 format.
> - UTF8BOM: Encodes in UTF-8 format with Byte Order Mark (BOM)
> - UTF8NoBOM: Encodes in UTF-8 format without Byte Order Mark (BOM)
> - UTF32: Encodes in UTF-32 format.
>
> Beginning with PowerShell 6.2, the Encoding parameter also allows numeric IDs of registered code pages (like -Encoding 1251) or string names of registered code pages (like -Encoding "windows-1251"). For more information, see the .NET documentation for Encoding.CodePage.

Comment: Unless the tag powershell-core is used, you IMO can't presume PowerShell version 6.

Comment: This has been a feature for [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-3.0) since at least PS version 3. Note that the last paragraph on the help page mentions what changed for PowerShell 6.

Comment: You are linking the PSv6 docs in the answer, and the cited UTF8(no)BOM encodings are PSv6+.

Comment: So go and use the menu to change the documentation version if you're using a different version. Without a version being stated it's fine to assume the latest version - in most cases PS is also downward compatible. Tab completion will tell you what's available for your installation. If you really think it's such an issue feel free to post you own answer. Regardless of what the default value is using `-Encoding` will allow the original poster to exclusively set the encoding he needs. Thanks for taking your time to comment.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, out-file or ">" or ">>" defaults to "unicode" or utf16 encoding.  You can even mix two encodings in the same file with ">>" or "out-file -append".  You can use set-content instead or "out-file -encoding utf8".  Actually set-content defaults to ansi encoding.  But without special characters, it will be the same as utf8 (without the bom), or you can use a -encoding option with set-content as well.  Notepad defaults to ansi, but can recognize utf8 or unicode even without bom's or encoding signatures.

```
powershell -Command "(gc myfile.csv) -replace '{NULL}', '' | set-content myfile_replaced.csv"
```